# Updating a table with a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-update

I'm trying to update a MySQL table and I keep getting a message stating that "you cannot use target table titles" for update in FROM clause.

This is my UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE titles
SET sales = sales * 0.5
WHERE sales > (SELECT AVG(sales) FROM titles);
```

I'm expecting the average sales to increase by 0.5 FROM titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try uisng a join with subquery

```
UPDATE titles t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AVG(sales) my_avg 
  FROM titles
) t2  on t1.sales > t2.my_avg
SET sales = sales * 0.5
```

Comment: That works. Do I need to use table alias for all my tables and columns?

Comment: is better  for readliblity ..  but if there not the same column name between the tables  the  db engine resolve correctly the reference  .. the explict table alias in mandatory when the same column is in two table  .. (in this case not)